# Sed Insert Multiple Lines

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to do an insert with sed (having just read up on it) and i'm being stumped by trying to insert multiple lines?

What i'm currently doing is:

```
sed -i "${line} i\
        /* Name - ID */ \
        select  @ID = NULL \
        from    Animals \
        where   VrsnID = @VrsnID \
        and     Request= \"Request\" \
 \
" animalNames.txt
```

Note `echo $line` == 131

**New Problem**

Everything appears on one line in the output? (also missing the first indent)

```
/* Name - ID */        select  @ID = NULL         from    Animals         where   VrsnID = @VrsnID         and     Request= "Request"
```

**Resolved**

But this throws:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unknown command: `
'
```

Any idea why?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Which version of sed do you use ? GNU/BSD ?

Comment: GNU sorry didn't realize that made a dif

Comment: Works here, GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: I'm not sure what i've changed but it works now, but everything is on one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the new trouble :
Use double backslash `\\`

Comment: Amazing thank you, why could I not find this anywhere in google (must have made 20+ searches for "sed multiple line insert")

Comment: Because for multiline it's better to use AWK. (in my opinion)

Comment: On a side note, is it possible to read a file for the insert "contents" instead of C&P into the sed command?

Comment: @PezCuckow : Yes, with `-f` argument. You can make sed's script file.

Comment: Another side note - remember that this doesn't work the same with the sed in MacOSX.

Answer (score 15):

In a shell script, backslash+newline expands to nothing. It's a way to continue to the next line without actually having a newline in the string. So what sed sees is just one big line. Compare:

```
$ echo "foo\
> bar"
foobar
$ echo "foo
> bar"
foo
bar
```

You need to pass a backslash and a newline to sed, so escape the backslash by putting another backslash before it.

```
sed -i "${line} i\\
        /* Name - ID */ \\
        select  @ID = NULL \\
        from    Animals \\
        where   VrsnID = @VrsnID \\
        and     Request= \"Request\" \\

" animalNames.txt
```

This may be more readable if you pass the script on the standard input as a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). You need to leave expansion on to substitute `${line}`, so you still need to double the backslash.

```
sed -i -f - animalNames.txt <<EOF
${line} i\\
        /* Name - ID */ \\
        select  @ID = NULL \\
        from    Animals \\
        where   VrsnID = @VrsnID \\
        and     Request= "Request" \\

EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for all the further info Gilles!

Comment: +1 for the heredoc version.  Was struggling to get an inline command working with multiple lines containing various significant meta chars and quotes.  This method worked perfectly first time, and is much cleaner, so will be my goto in future.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed ${line}'i\
    /* Name - ID */ \
    select  @ID = NULL \
    from    Animals \
    where   VrsnID = @VrsnID \
    and     Request= \"Request\"

' animalNames.txt
```

Comment: You need to use \\ for a new line

Comment: @PezCuckow for me (using GNU sed and bash) a single \ is suffice.